# Genus of the Category of Natural Numbers?

Tags: number-theory, graph-theory, algebraic-topology, category-theory

I began to consider the following chain of ideas: Consider a Category  $\text{Cat} \ X$ of objects of a type $X$. One can view the Category as a graph (objects are nodes and morphisms as directed edges) and thus it's natural to ask about topological properties of these graphs.

The simplest example I came up with was to let $X$ be $\mathbb{N}$, and let the arrows map $a \rightarrow b$ in the natural way if $b|a$.

Does $\text{Cat} \ \mathbb{N}$ then have finite genus?

Some Analysis:

There is one true sink "1", the 2nd order sinks are prime numbers, 3rd order sinks are semiprimes, etc...

Comment: How do you define the genus of a directed graph?

Comment: @Levent Presumably as https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genus_(mathematics)#Graph_theory.

Comment: Yes! sorry about the delay

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that the set of powers of $2$, after forgetting the direction of the arrows, forms a copy of the complete graph on countably infinitely many vertices, $K_\omega$. This means the genus is in fact infinite.